# Removing CS6 using psexec within Powershell on multiple machines

Tags: xml, powershell, command, psexec

Trying to run a script to remove CS6 on multiple machines by running psexec within powershell. The command for removing CS6 (appending an XML file to the locally installed setup file) works when run using psexec within the command line but fails when I use Powershell. The error I get for every machine is

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\DWA\Setup.exe
>   exited on VM08002745E4AD with error code 16."

Any ideas?

Script below

```
#get list of computers    
$computers = gc "C:\Remove CS6\adobe_cs6_hosts.txt"

#Loop through each computer
Foreach ( $computer in $computers )
{
    #copy XML file
    Copy "C:\Remove CS6\uninstall-en_IL.xml" "\\$computer\c$" -force

    #Uninstall CS6
    try
    {
        "$computer attempting 32 bit uninstall"
        $output = cmd /c "psexec \\$computer `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\DWA\Setup.exe`" --mode=Silent --deploymentFile=`"\\$computer\c$\uninstall-en_IL.xml`" 2>&1"

        "$computer $output"
    }
    catch
    {
        "$computer attempting 64 bit uninstall"
    }

    try
    {
        $output = cmd /c "psexec \\$computer  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\DWA\Setup.exe" --mode=Silent --deploymentFile="\\$computer\c$\uninstall-en_IL.xml`" 2>&1"
        "$computer $output"
    }
    catch
    {
        "Failed to uninstall CS6"
    }            
}    
pause 

Foreach ( $computer in $computers )
{
    #Delete uninstall.xml
    Remove-item “\\$computer\c$\uninstall-en_IL.xml”   
}
```

Comment: And here's the original psexec command which came from a blog post

If you copy and paste though it wont work because you need a double dash (–). Copy/paste only places one dash (-). This is the correct command:

For 32bit
“C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\DWA\Setup.exe” –mode=Silent –deploymentFile=”%PATH_TO_XML%\uninstall-en_US.xml”

For 64bit
“C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\DWA\Setup.exe” –mode=Silent –deploymentFile=”%PATH_TO_XML%\uninstall-en_US.xml”

Comment: error code 16 means that `setup.exe` was not able to load the deployment file

Comment: any idea why though? the same syntax works fine when running from psexec in the command prompt!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that all the machines have the file `uninstall-en_IL.xml` in the root of their `C:` drives?

Comment: no worries I've fixed it turns out you need to escape the double hyphen e.g. "`--"

Comment: Cool, you should add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to escape the double hyphen e.g. `` `-- ``